# Can't set image to jsPlumb endpoint

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jsplumb

I'm using jsPlumb library in my project and I have a function that changes endpoint images if they are connected. I call it when the page loads and everything works fine, but when I call it on connection event, nothing happens. Here is my code:

```
function changeEndpointImage(){
            var elem = $('.tableBody');   //These are my connectable elements
            for(var i=0;i<elem.length;i++)
            {
                 var eps=jsPlumb.getEndpoints($(elem[i]));  //Getting endpoints for each of the connectable elements
                 for(var j=0;j<eps.length;j++)
                 {
                      if(eps[j].connections.length!=0)  //Checking if any of them have connections
                           eps[j].setImage("images/styled_radiobutton.png");  //Setting another image
                 }
            }
        }
jsPlumb.bind("connection", function(connection) {
     changeEndpointImage();

     //I have also tried this method commented below, but nothing.
     //connection.sourceEndpoint.setImage("images/styled_radiobutton.png");
     //connection.targetEndpoint.setImage("images/styled_radiobutton.png");

});
```

I'm also trying to change endpoint images back to the first look if the connection is detached, but in this case, only the source endpoint gets changed, target remains the same:

```
jsPlumb.bind("connectionDetached", function(connection) {
    connection.targetEndpoint.setImage("images/rsz_styled_radiobutton.png");
    connection.sourceEndpoint.setImage("images/rsz_styled_radiobutton.png");
});
```

What am I missing or how can I fix this problem?

EDIT: Here is jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/vaxobasilidze/cg3hkde7/

Drag few items to the right div, press "Add new link" and try to attach detach connections. You will see that endpoints don't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to this in jsPlumb google group. I have set endpoint `Blank` instead of `Image`, added `cssClass: 'myClass'` property and then styled `.myClass { background: url(...) }`. This does what I wanted, because connected endpoints get additional class `'jsplumb-endpoint-connected'` and I can set another image as a background to this class.